# Marcar movimientos disponibles en ajedrez

Tags: java

Espero que puedan responder a la duda que tengo.

Lo que quiero realizar con mi programa de ajedrez es que cuando yo seleccione una pieza del tablero pueda marcar todas las casillas a donde esta pieza se puede mover, un ejemplo seria el peon, suponiendo que es el primer movimiento que hare cualquier peon que seleccione tendra 2 casillas posibles a las cuales podra moverse, puede ser 1 casilla hacia el frente o 2 casillas hacia el frente. La forma en las que quisiera marcar estas casillas son con alguna imagen como lo hago al seleccionar alguna pieza del ajedrez asi como lo hago en la clase paintcomponent de la clase Display.

Aqui les dejo un video de lo que quier conseguir, no es necesario que lo adelanten, el videos se reproducira en el segundo exacto de lo que quiero conseguir: https://youtu.be/Ytpb35VO4gI?t=15s

Ya intente creando diversas clases para mi programa y diferentes condiciones, ningun metodo me a funcionado.

*En el caso de requerirlo, les dejo el link del proyecto completo: https://mega.nz/#!MV4zxaKT!GJ80XYladMdxt7_84pSbgZ02h46z-zRt4eK7eNPzTwA*

**CLASE GAME**

```
package chess;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static chess.PieceColor.*;

class Game {

    Game() {
        _moves = new ArrayList<Move>();
        _gui = new ChessGUI("Ajedrez", this);
        newGame();
    }

    public void newGame() {
        initializeBoard();
        _moves.clear();
        _turn = WHITE;
        _selectedX = -1;
        _selectedY = -1;
    }

    public void quit() {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void undoMove() {
        if (_moves.size() > 0) {
            Move lastMove = _moves.remove(_moves.size() - 1);
            makeMove(lastMove.undoMove());
            _moves.remove(_moves.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public void makeMove(Move move) {
        _moves.add(move);
        if (!move.isDouble()) {
            SingleMove singlemove = (SingleMove) move;
            executeMove(singlemove);
        } else {
            DoubleMove doublemove = (DoubleMove) move;
            executeMove(doublemove.move1());
            executeMove(doublemove.move2());
        }
        _turn = _turn.opposite();
    }

    private void executeMove(SingleMove move) {
        _board[move.x1()][move.y1()] = move.replace();
        if (move.replace() != null) {
            move.replace().setLocation(move.x1(), move.y1());
        }
        _board[move.x2()][move.y2()] = move.selected();
        if (move.selected() != null) {
            move.selected().setLocation(move.x2(), move.y2());
        }
        if (move.target() != null) {
            move.target().setLocation(-1, -1);
        }
    }

    public boolean inCheck(PieceColor color) {
        int x = kingX(color);
        int y = kingY(color);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                Piece p = get(i, j);
                if (p != null && p.color() == color.opposite()
                    && p.canCapture(x, y)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean noMoves() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                Piece p = get(i, j);
                if (p != null && p.color() == _turn) {
                    if (p.hasMove()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean guarded(int x, int y) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                Piece p = get(i, j);
                if (p != null && p.color() == _turn.opposite()
                    && p.canCapture(x, y)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Piece get(int i, int j) {
        return _board[i][j];
    }

    public Piece lastMover() {
        return _moves.get(_moves.size() - 1).movedPiece();
    }

    private void initializeBoard() {
        Piece blackRo0 = new Rook(BLACK, this, 0, 0);
        Piece blackKn0 = new Knight(BLACK, this, 1, 0);
        Piece blackBi0 = new Bishop(BLACK, this, 2, 0);
        Piece blackQu0 = new Queen(BLACK, this, 3, 0);
        _blackKi = new King(BLACK, this, 4, 0);
        Piece blackBi1 = new Bishop(BLACK, this, 5, 0);
        Piece blackKn1 = new Knight(BLACK, this, 6, 0);
        Piece blackRo1 = new Rook(BLACK, this, 7, 0);
        Piece blackPa0 = new Pawn(BLACK, this, 0, 1);
        Piece blackPa1 = new Pawn(BLACK, this, 1, 1);
        Piece blackPa2 = new Pawn(BLACK, this, 2, 1);
        Piece blackPa3 = new Pawn(BLACK, this, 3, 1);
        Piece blackPa4 = new Pawn(BLACK, this, 4, 1);
        Piece blackPa5 = new Pawn(BLACK, this, 5, 1);
        Piece blackPa6 = new Pawn(BLACK, this, 6, 1);
        Piece blackPa7 = new Pawn(BLACK, this, 7, 1);
        Piece whiteRo0 = new Rook(WHITE, this, 0, 7);
        Piece whiteKn0 = new Knight(WHITE, this, 1, 7);
        Piece whiteBi0 = new Bishop(WHITE, this, 2, 7);
        Piece whiteQu0 = new Queen(WHITE, this, 3, 7);
        _whiteKi = new King(WHITE, this, 4, 7);
        Piece whiteBi1 = new Bishop(WHITE, this, 5, 7);
        Piece whiteKn1 = new Knight(WHITE, this, 6, 7);
        Piece whiteRo1 = new Rook(WHITE, this, 7, 7);
        Piece whitePa0 = new Pawn(WHITE, this, 0, 6);
        Piece whitePa1 = new Pawn(WHITE, this, 1, 6);
        Piece whitePa2 = new Pawn(WHITE, this, 2, 6);
        Piece whitePa3 = new Pawn(WHITE, this, 3, 6);
        Piece whitePa4 = new Pawn(WHITE, this, 4, 6);
        Piece whitePa5 = new Pawn(WHITE, this, 5, 6);
        Piece whitePa6 = new Pawn(WHITE, this, 6, 6);
        Piece whitePa7 = new Pawn(WHITE, this, 7, 6);
        Piece[][] newBoard = {
            {blackRo0, blackPa0, null, null, null, null, whitePa0, whiteRo0},
            {blackKn0, blackPa1, null, null, null, null, whitePa1, whiteKn0},
            {blackBi0, blackPa2, null, null, null, null, whitePa2, whiteBi0},
            {blackQu0, blackPa3, null, null, null, null, whitePa3, whiteQu0},
            {_blackKi, blackPa4, null, null, null, null, whitePa4, _whiteKi},
            {blackBi1, blackPa5, null, null, null, null, whitePa5, whiteBi1},
            {blackKn1, blackPa6, null, null, null, null, whitePa6, whiteKn1},
            {blackRo1, blackPa7, null, null, null, null, whitePa7, whiteRo1} };
        _board = newBoard;
    }

    public int kingX(PieceColor color) {
        if (color == WHITE) {
            return _whiteKi.getX();
        } else {
            return _blackKi.getX();
        }
    }

    public int kingY(PieceColor color) {
        if (color == WHITE) {
            return _whiteKi.getY();
        } else {
            return _blackKi.getY();
        }
    }

    public void setSelectedX(int x) {
        _selectedX = x;
    }

    public void setSelectedY(int y) {
        _selectedY = y;
    }

    public int selectedX() {
        return _selectedX;
    }

    public int selectedY() {
        return _selectedY;
    }

    public Piece[][] board() {
        return _board;
    }

    public PieceColor turn() {
        return _turn;
    }

    private Piece[][] _board;

    private ChessGUI _gui;

    private PieceColor _turn;

    private List<Move> _moves;

    private King _blackKi;

    private King _whiteKi;

    private int _selectedX;

    private int _selectedY;

}
```

**CLASE DEL DISPLAY**

```
package chess;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

class GameDisplay extends Pad {

    public static final double MULTIPLIER = 0.7;

    public static final int BOARD = (int) Math.round(700 * MULTIPLIER);

    public static final int CELL = (int) Math.round(74 * MULTIPLIER);

    public static final int MARGIN = (int) Math.round(53 * MULTIPLIER);

    public GameDisplay(Game game) {
        _game = game;
        setPreferredSize(BOARD, BOARD);
    }

    private Image getImage(String name) {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/chess/images/"
            + name);
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(in);
        } catch (IOException excp) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private Image getPieceImage(Piece piece) {
        return getImage("pieces/" + piece.imageString() + ".png");
    }

    private void paintPiece(Graphics2D g, Piece piece, int x, int y) {
        if (piece != null) {
            g.drawImage(getPieceImage(piece), x, y, CELL, CELL, null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {
        Rectangle b = g.getClipBounds();
        g.fillRect(0, 0, b.width, b.height);
        g.drawImage(getImage("chessboard.jpg"), 0, 0, BOARD, BOARD, null);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        if (_game.inCheck(_game.turn())) {
            g.drawImage(getImage("inCheck.png"),
                CELL * _game.kingX(_game.turn()) + MARGIN,
                CELL * _game.kingY(_game.turn()) + MARGIN, CELL, CELL, null);
        }
        if (_game.selectedX() != -1) {
            g.drawImage(getImage("selected.png"),
                CELL * _game.selectedX() + MARGIN,
                CELL * _game.selectedY() + MARGIN, CELL, CELL, null);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                paintPiece(g, _game.get(i, j),
                    CELL * i + MARGIN, CELL * j + MARGIN);
            }
        }
    }

    private final Game _game;

}
```

Comment: Deberías explicar mejor cuál es el problema. ¿Es un problema al calcular las posiciones? ¿O las posiciones se calculan mal pero el problema es al mostrarlas? ¿Cuál es el exactamente el error (una excepción, un valor incorrecto, no pasa nada)? Intenta poner un ejemplo sencillo (por ejemplo un tablero con solo una torre, y lo que obtengo es esto).

Comment: NO entiendo bien tu problema ya que no lo expresas de manera clara, pero mira [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13517401/8933039)  o [esta otra información](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1831408/8933039) quizás pueda ayudar.

Comment: @SJuan76 ya especifique de mejor forma lo que quiero conseguir espero que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez ya especifique de mejor forma lo que quiero conseguir espero que me puedas ayudar.

Comment: Así a grosso modo te diría que ya que tienes un método makeValidMove que te dice los movimientos válidos te bases en él para que la clase de cada pieza consulte dichas posiciones al hacer click.

Comment: @Kiko_L Intentare a ver que me sale porque creeme que ya eh intentado de todo, gracias por tu comentario y espero que funcione :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de pasar un tiempo analizando el juego he conseguido marcar los movimientos validos para cada una de las piezas.

Los pasos claves son:

**Modificar la interfaz Piece** para que las piezas que la implementar deban incorporar el método ArrayList getValidMoves():

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public interface Piece {

    String imageString();
    PieceColor color();
    PieceType type();
    boolean makeValidMove(int a, int b);
    boolean hasMove();
    boolean canCapture(int a, int b);
    void setLocation(int x, int y);
    ArrayList<Point> getValidMoves();
}
```

El paso siguiente es **implementar getValidMoves() en cada una de las piezas**, además de **incorporar algunos métodos privados auxiliares**. Te dejo el ejemplo de Pawn, en el resto de piezas es similar:

```
public ArrayList<Point> getValidMoves(){
    ArrayList<Point> validMoves = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for (int x=0;x<8;x++)
    {
        for (int y=0;y<8;y++)
        {
            //System.out.println("x =" + x + ", y = " + y);
            if (isValidMove(x,y)) {
                //System.out.println("Is valid move");
                validMoves.add(new Point(x,y)); 
            }
        }
    }
    return validMoves;
}
public boolean isValidMove(int a, int b){
    if (_y == start()) {
        if (b == _y + 2 * direction()) {
            if (a == _x && _game.get(a, _y + direction()) == null
                && _game.get(a, b) == null) {
                Move move = new SingleMove(this, _x, _y,
                    _game.get(a, b), a, b);
                return simulateMoveCareful(move);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (b == _y + direction()) {
        if (a == _x && _game.get(a, b) == null) {
            if (b == start() + 6 * direction()) {
                SingleMove move1 = new SingleMove(this, _x, _y,
                    _game.get(a, b), a, b);
                Piece newQu = new Queen(_color, _game, a, b);
                SingleMove move2 = new SingleMove(newQu, a, b, this, a, b);
                DoubleMove move = new DoubleMove(move1, move2);
                return simulateMoveCareful(move);
            } else {
                Move move = new SingleMove(this, _x, _y,
                    _game.get(a, b), a, b);
                return simulateMoveCareful(move);
            }
        } else if (Math.abs(a - _x) == 1 && _game.get(a, b) != null
            && _game.get(a, b).color() != _color) {
            if (b == start() + 6 * direction()) {
                SingleMove move1 = new SingleMove(this, _x, _y,
                    _game.get(a, b), a, b);
                Piece newQueen = new Queen(_color, _game, a, b);
                SingleMove move2 = new SingleMove(newQueen, a, b,
                    this, a, b);
                DoubleMove move = new DoubleMove(move1, move2);
                return simulateMoveCareful(move);
            } else {
                Move move = new SingleMove(this, _x, _y,
                    _game.get(a, b), a, b);
                return simulateMoveCareful(move);
            }
        } else if (Math.abs(a - _x) == 1 && _game.get(a, b) == null
            && _y == start() + 3 * direction() && _game.get(a, _y) != null
            && _game.get(a, _y).color() != _color
            && _game.get(a, _y).type() == PAWN
            && _game.get(a, _y) == _game.lastMover()) {
            return true;

        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}

private boolean simulateMoveCareful(Move move) {
    _game.makeMove(move);
    boolean moveSimulationResult = true;
    if (_game.inCheck(_game.turn().opposite())) {
        moveSimulationResult = false;
    }
    _game.undoMove();
    return moveSimulationResult;
}
```

Como puedes ver, y tal y como también apuntaba Kiko_L, **te debes de apoyar en el uso del método makeValidMove** para crear isValidMove. Además de sustituir makeValidMove por simulateValidMove a fin de evitar el movimiento(_game.undoMove()).

**Finalmente, solo será necesario modificar ligeramente el método paintComponent(Graphics2D g) de la clase GameDisplay** además de crear una **nueva imagen png** que debe servir para marcar las posiciones validas:

```
public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics2D g) {
    Rectangle b = g.getClipBounds();
    g.fillRect(0, 0, b.width, b.height);
    g.drawImage(getImage("chessboard.jpg"), 0, 0, BOARD, BOARD, null);
    if (_game.inCheck(_game.turn())) {
        g.drawImage(getImage("inCheck.png"),
            CELL * _game.kingX(_game.turn()) + MARGIN,
            CELL * _game.kingY(_game.turn()) + MARGIN, CELL, CELL, null);
    }
    if (_game.selectedX() != -1) {
        //Dibujamos un cuadrado sobre la pieza seleccionada
        g.drawImage(getImage("selected.png"),
            CELL * _game.selectedX() + MARGIN,
            CELL * _game.selectedY() + MARGIN, CELL, CELL, null);

        //Dibujamos cuadrados para cada uno de los movimientos validos de la pieza selecconada
        Piece p = _game.get(_game.selectedX(), _game.selectedY());
        for (java.awt.Point validMovementPoint:p.getValidMoves())
        {
            g.drawImage(getImage("validMovement.png"),
                    CELL * validMovementPoint.x + MARGIN,
                    CELL * validMovementPoint.y + MARGIN, CELL, CELL, null);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            paintPiece(g, _game.get(i, j),
                CELL * i + MARGIN, CELL * j + MARGIN);
        }
    }
}
```

Como comentario final, decir que **hay mucho código común en las clases** y que este podría ser ubicado en una **superclasse abstracta** llamada Piece que implementase IPiece, pasando a renombrar la Interface Piece como IPiece.

Saludos,

David.

Comment: Tu respuesta me sirvio mas de lo que te imaginas, ahora entiendo como funciona esto de marcar los movimientos validos ademas de que el hecho de reducir el codigo me quito un pequeño lag que tenia mi ajedrez al momento de ejecutarse, gracias de verdad :D

Comment: Gracias a ti. Estamos en contacto.